# pgadmin 4.30 : unable to backup and restore database

Tags: pgadmin-4

I want backup and restore a schema with pgadmin 4 and postgresql 10.5
but it doesn't work : no data is imported

During export, I try tar format and backup type file.

No message errors juste these lines when i restore:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: implied data-only restore
```

Do you have a idea

thanks a lot ?

Comment: on another server the dump restore take several millisecondes et no data imported ....

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it works if I create a new database but it doesn't work in a same database.

A idea ?